# Error when assigning dashboard to new user Liferay 7.3.5

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

We are using liferay 7.3.5 and have about 600 users that make use of the personal dashboard. When a new user is added, they get assigned a profile and dashboard programmatically. however, recently we have ran into a problem regarding the assigning of the dashboard.

when a new user is added to the platform, the profile assigns as normal, but the dashboard will say (on the "profile and dashboard" tab of the new user) "This user does not have any private pages."

we have chosen several different templates all of which assign without fail. we have also tried to deconstruct the existing template, but only when it has been entirely cleared and is basically a fresh start, does it work again. The dashboard still works for any of the users that have gotten assigned it before it 'broke'.

this is the error code we recieved. we have not been able to trace back the FileEntry ID. we have been stuck on this matter for a while now, but it's not an option for us to rebuild a completely new dashboard.

```
2022-05-27 13:51:38.335 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-12][SitesImpl:1927] Unable to export layout set prototype 207822
    com.liferay.exportimport.kernel.lar.PortletDataException: No FileEntry exists with the key {fileEntryId=884352}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this error and/or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your own custom servicebuilder service (with the namespace declaration GB) has been redeployed with a newer version and might be incompatible:

> Build namespace GB has build number 54 which is newer than 36

You'll find more information about Upgrade Processes in Liferay's documentation, or in these two blog articles - this documentation would go beyond the scope of a simple answer on stackoverflow:

- [ServiceBuilder and Upgrade Processes](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/servicebuilder-and-upgrade-processes)
- [Building in Upgrade Support](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/building-in-upgrade-support)

Comment: Hi Olaf, thank you for the response!

We have removed the custom servicebuilder to test if the error persists. 
unfortunately, it does albeit without the "Build namespace GB has build number 54 which is newer than 36" line.

We have read through the documentation you linked, but found no solutions there. do you have any further guidance?